# How can I call Javascript function from razor?

Tags: javascript, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to use google maps in one of my screens. I am able to load the Google maps during the window.onload. That script is in my site.js file. then I want for each bicycle I want to display all last locations if available. I have been searching the web and this forum but the answers I could find one that help me forward. Based on what I have read this should work but when I use a breakpoint the function ShowLocation is never called. Any help is appreciated

```
@model AccountViewModel

<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowLocation(lt, lng) {
    var googleLatLong = new google.maps.LatLng(lt, lng);
    var markerOptions = {
        position: googleLatLong,
        map: map,
        clickable: true
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

}

</script>

<div>
    <h2> bicycle Locations </h2>
</div>


<div id="map" class="col-md-8 col-sm-6">
Map Loading....
</div>


 @foreach (var bicycle in Model.Bicycles)
  {
     int i = 0;
     if (bicycle.LastLocationID != 0)
     {
         var location = Model.LastKnowLocations.FirstOrDefault(l => 
         l.ID == bicycle.LastLocationID);
         var lattitude = location.Latitude;
         var longitude = location.Longitude;

         <script type="text/javascript">
              ShowLocation(lattitude, longitude)
         </script>

    }
}
```

Comment: when you are calling the function remove "function" keyword. "function ShowLocation(lattitude, longitude)" should be "ShowLocation(lattitude, longitude);"

Comment: Hi, thanks that was an error. Not sure how it could there. However it does not resolve the issue. The java code is skipped.

Comment: I found the issue. For some reason when using the function from google map API to locate the current user position navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayLocation, displayError); it has the effect that javascripts are ignored. That is not called by the displayLocation function. So trying to add at a later stage the markers the javascript is being ignored. So I when I do not use that function the codes works. I can not explain it why in the other case the java script is being ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You should call showlocation function from $(document).ready.
Having loop in razor will just render the script section.

Comment: Hi, tried that one but no luck - code block continues to be skipped.